# When should I use styles.scss in Angular and When should use the scss of a component

Tags: angular

I have three identical components: a carousel of suggested products, a carousel of products with discount, a carousel of featured products. Those components have a bunch of css styles applied to them. Of course that those css classes are nearly identical. Should I repeat the css on each component or should I place the shared classes on the global styles.scss. Which one is the best practice ? If a use the global styles.scss I avoid repetition and can apply changes to components in one place. But how about if a want to use the component in another project. I would have to pick all the classes on the styles.scss file. Again, which one is the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

Component styles are used to encapsulate the style.

Once compiled, your style, such as

```
.myClass { color: blue; }
```

Becomes

```
.myClass[ng_contentc0] { color: blue; }
```

That `ng_contentc0` is an attribute that is dynamically added to every HTML tag of your component. This prevents your classes from colliding from one component to another.

When using the global style sheet, ususally `styles.[ext]`, you simply create a global style : every tag having the class will have the style.

In your case, you should use neither of those : you should

- Create a new CSS file, called `carousel.scss` or whatever
- Import that file in all of your 3 component decorators, under `styleUrls` (which is an array)

With this technique, you create an encapsulated style sheet, that you can use on several components, and that won't collide with any external CSS style you might have made/installed.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a best practice, best is what works for you.

Small projects usually doesnt care much about these, if it works then thats fine.

Large projects often struggle in scaling css, reaches a bottleneck in terms of styling sooner or later and changing anything breaks everything. Scaling CSS has many approaches.

You can use [BEM, SMACSS etc](http://getbem.com/introduction/) and can help you manage your CSS easily.

Another Component based CSS approach is [scoped CSS](https://css-tricks.com/saving-the-day-with-scoped-css/), that is exactly what you are doing when writing CSS in component file in Angular as angular does its own polyfilled scoping. (Shouldn't be using `/deep/`)

> Those components have a bunch of css styles applied to them. Of course
>   that those css classes are nearly identical

You probably have to re imagine the granularity of your components or use mixins, inheritance etc in sass to manage your identical *features*

DISCLAIMER: I am not an expert in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I think the real question here is why do you have three identical components. Maybe a better option would be to only have one component that is implemented in a more generic way or maybe have one component that contains three components that make the difference.

The global styles.scss is for the whole application, so styles that are really specific to components should rather be placed inside the components, duplicated components result in duplicated code (that includes scss) so you should try to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to this problem is `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` which will add your style in your global style section.

So you can directly copy paste your component in any project. It will work like charm.

Here is an example : -

**your.component.ts**

```
import {ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-zippy',
  templateUrl: 'my-zippy.component.html',
  styles: [`
    .zippy {
      background: green;
    }
  `],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
class ZippyComponent {
  @Input() title: string;
}
```

Hope this will help